# How do we prove that even perfect numbers have a factorization in terms of Marsenne primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

There is a proof from Euler that if n is an even perfect number (i.e. $\sigma(n)\equiv\Sigma_{d|n}d=n$) then n has a factorization $n=2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$ with p prime and $2^p-1$ a Marsenne prime (i.e. a prime of the given form). I can follow most of the proof but I get stuck on an intermediate step. The proof goes as follows:

$n=2^km$ with $m\ge1$ and m odd.

Since $\sigma$ is multiplicative and the two factors are coprime, $\sigma(m)=\sigma(2^k)\sigma(m)=(2^{k+1}-1)\sigma(m)$

$(2^{k+1}-1)|\sigma(m)$ where "|" means "divides.

$\sigma(m)=2^{k+1}c$ we need to show that $c=1$

$2^{k+1}m=(2^{k+1}-1)2^{k+1}c$

$m=2^{k+1}c$

Assume $c>1$ and derive a contradiction

$m>c>1$

**Here is where I get stuck**

$\sigma(m)\ge 1+c+m$

I can only see that $\sigma(m)\ge 1+m$. If m were prime we would have equality here.

For completeness I will show the rest of the proof: $\sigma(m)\ge 1+c+(2^{k+1}-1)c=1+2^{k+1}c$

This contradicts the fact that $\sigma(m)=2^{k+1}c$, so $c=1$

$m=2^{k+1}-1$

$\sigma(m)=2^{k+1}=m+1$ so the only positive divisors of m are 1 and m, meaning that m is prime and therefore a Marsenne prime.

Comment: There are several typos and inaccuracies in this proof, which are making it hard to diagnose exactly what you want to know. However, the inequality $\sigma(m) \ge 1+c+m$, under the assumption-for-the-sake-of-contradiction $c>1$, is because $1$, $c$, and $m$ are distinct divisors of $m$.

Comment: I see; thank you. Can you point out an inaccuracy or typo so that I may correct it?

Comment: You are mixing up $n$ and $m$ in several places.

Comment: This is a standard proof which you can find in proof-wiki, for example. Actually, we know all perfect numbers upto millions of digits. Concerning odd perfect numbers, the situation is unfortunately worse. Among many restrictions, we know that it must exceed $10^{1500}$. None is known and it is conjectured that none exists.

Comment: By the way, primes of the form $2^p-1$ (for which necessarily $p$ is prime itself) are called "Mersenne primes" , not "Marsenne primes"

Comment: Correction : Of course I mean "we know all EVEN perfect numbers upto millions of digits"